# Live search engine logic behind query

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, logic

I have problems creating a multiple field live search engine using AJAX and PHP.

Up to now there was no need to search for multiple fields, so I had a simple query that worked fine for only one field.

Because of a live search using `onkeyup` function I recognized some problems. The first problem i need to explain:

The structure of the table is quite simple: `zipcode | city`

For example, someone enters `12345`; of course this would be the zipcode. But what in case if someone enters `12345 hometown` so the first keyword would be the zipcode, second the city?

The keywords will be split by using `preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search_term)` so as a result I receive an array with the single keywords that will be searched for. in the case above it would be: `key[0] => 12345` and `key[1] => hometown`.

The query I use is like:

```
$where = "";

$search_term = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search_term); //splits the whole string into single keywords
$total_search_terms = count($search_term); //counts the array-keys from $search_term

foreach ($search_term as $key=>$single_term) {

        $where .= "`zipcode` LIKE '$single_term%' OR `city` LIKE '$single_term%' ";

        if ($key != ($total_search_terms - 1)){ //adds AND to the query in case in case of a non empty array-key 
            $where .= " AND ";
        }

}

$query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE $where");
...
```

Okay, so far so good. Now the problem is that the keywords can match each field again and again.

To give further example:

In case from above entering `12345 hometown` it means that `key[0] => 12345`  can match field `zipcode` OR `city`. This condition is egual to `key[1] => hometown`, even this can match field `zipcode` OR `city`. So ,even when entering other way round: `hometown 12345` means the same.

And this is the first problem I have.

I'm looking for a logic to structure the query. So in case of  entering `12345 hometown` I would like to have something like that:

When `key[0] => 12345` matches field `zipcode` dont check `key[1] => hometown` if that matches in `zipcode` OR `city` because `key[0]` matches already in `zipcode` so it´s quite logical that `key[1]` needs to be `city`.

**UPDATE**

Okay, to tell my second problem I would like you to have a look at the answer from `david strachan`
He mentioned that a problem will be caused when the city contains more than one string. Let's say the search string would be something like:

```
12345 New York
```

The keys would be:

```
key[0] => 12345, key[1] => New, key[2] => York
```

Okay, now the problem is that I could check if one of the keys contains integers or not and in case of a string-length of exactly 5 I know that it will be the zipcode.

```
key[0] => 12345 //if ( stringlen(key[0|) === 5) === true  && is_int(key[0]) === true) {zipcode}
```

So far so good but the real problem is the logic behind the strings of the cities. My first thoughts were that I could say that all keys that do not contain integers must be the city so I could convert them into one key.

```
key[1] => New, key[2] => York //if ( !is_int(key[1|) === true && !is_int(key[2|) === true)  {$create_one_key = array_fill_keys(key[1], key[1]+key[2]);}
```

Alright, but what in case I would like to add street names in the future? I do not know how to separate and test for street name and even for the city name.

Comment: `when key[0] => 12345 matches field zipcode dont check key[1] => hometown if that matches in zipcode OR city because key[0] matches already in zipcode so it's quiet logical that key[1] needs to be city.` why do you want to do that? For optimization purposes I guess?

Comment: Hi there. Looking through your questions, I notice they're all written in lower case. Your English seems to be fine, so can I trouble you to use initial capital letters? Occasionally people are taking the time to fix your questions to make them more readable, so you'd be saving them some time!

Comment: @halfer. Okay, thanks for this hint. I will remember that for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Ejay I want it that way because of the second problem i got. i will update my question to give further information regarding this. thanks

Comment: You're over complicating the city name and street name thing I guess. Getting the users to enter comma separated address will solve **a lot** of your problems, e.g., _zipcode, city, street name_. Or better if you can use multiple input boxes

Comment: @Ejay :D hahaha... no I dont make it harder than it is. I need it this way round because i have a single input field at my index page. this is just a for a quick search to show whats already existing in the database. so i already know about how to search using different inputfields. that's quiet simple. but what in case if you do not have different inputfields and like its limited to only one inputfield like i have?!

Comment: what's so funny about it? never heard of KISS?

Comment: KISS? you do not mean the music band, right?

Comment: `stringlen(key[0]) === 5` could be paris?

Comment: @bonny see new answer using JQuery Autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use [**JQuery Autocomplete**](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to search MySQL database. The following code uses PDO.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zipsearch').autocomplete({source:'suggest.php', minLength:2});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    li.ui-menu-item { font-size:10px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>jQuery UI Autocomplete - With MySQL  </h2>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    Search:
    <input id="zipsearch" type="text" size ="60"/>
</form>
```

**suggest.php**

```
require("dbinfo.php");//db connection strings
// if the 'term' variable is not sent with the request, exit
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;
$term = $_REQUEST['term'];
 if (is_numeric($term)){
    $query = "SELECT * from ziptest WHERE zip LIKE ? OR address LIKE ? LIMIT 0,10";
  }else{
    $query = "SELECT * from ziptest WHERE city LIKE ? OR state LIKE ? LIMIT 0,10";  
  }
$term.="%";  

// connect to the database  
try {  
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
  // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$term);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$term);
    // setting the fetch mode  
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $stmt->execute();  
    $data = array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  
            $data[] = array(
                'label' => $row['address'] .', '. $row['city'] .', '. $row['state'] .', '.$row['zip'] ,
                'value' => "ID ".$row['id'] .': '.$row['address'] .', '. $row['city'] .', '. $row['state'] .', '.$row['zip']
            );
        }
    echo json_encode($data);
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]'). $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
}  
// close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

[**DEMO**](http://gleniffersystems.net46.net/jquery/autosuggest.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `$search_term[0]` is string(city) or  int(zipcode) by addition of 0 Then format query accordingly.

```
$search_term = '1234 paisley';
$search_term = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search_term); //splits the whole string into single keywords
$total_search_terms = count($search_term); //counts the array-keys from $search_term
$test = $search_term[0]+0;//If string returns 0
if($total_search_terms == 1){
    if ($test == 0 ){
        $where = "WHERE `city` LIKE `%$search_term[0]%`";
         }else{
        $where = "WHERE `zipcode` LIKE `%$search_term[0]%` ";
        }   
    }else{
    if ($test == 0 ){
        $where = "WHERE `zipcode` LIKE `%$search_term[1]%` AND `city` LIKE `%$search_term[0]%`";
        }else{
        $where = "WHERE `zipcode` LIKE `%$search_term[0]%` AND `city` LIKE `%$search_term[1]%`";
        }   
}   
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table $where";
echo $query;
```

One problem will be how you treat New York. I will leave you how to work this out.

**EDIT**

New York `$total_search_terms > 2`

Comment: hello and thank you very much for this answer. the problem you are talking about is exactly my second problem. what in case if i would like to add street names to the table or the city has more than one string?

Comment: This approach can be used with as long as the only integer value is zipcode and the city has one or more strings in the name(hint `$total_search_terms > 2`). If you want to search for street addresses you should ask a new question

Comment: Hello and sorry for my lateness. I*m still buisy at the momemt and can not answer immediately. I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: The `$search_term` will either `12345 New York` or `New York 12345` So if $total_search_terms > 2 either `$search_term[0]` or `$search_term[2]` will be zipcode. `stringlen(key[0]) === 5` could be paris?

Comment: stringlen(key[0]) === 5 could be paris? is quiet right but its just one of two conditions. so all zipcodes are exactly 5 characters long so that this is the first hint for a zipcode. the next one would be that is_int()===true/false will confirm that. okay, back to your hint $total_search_terms > 2 : how does it work that either [0] or [2] will be the zipcode? there are no conditions to check like is_int etc.? i'm a little bit confused about that. thanks.

Comment: ahhh... i got it. that´s why you automatically say that the input is exactly like 12345 New York or New York 12345.  i was already one step further because i thought what in case if the input is New 12345 York. This would be my third problem.

Comment: Third problem will also be fourth problem :) what in case i would like to add street names. lets say the input is like NEW 12345 YORK WALL STREET. This would mean that [1]+[3] = NEW YORK can be a city but even [1]+[4] = NEW WALL, or [1]+[5] = NEW STREET and so on... at the end i would need to check all keys against until the query fetches a row for city or street. afterwards it needs to be delete the keys that already matches and check for the rest?

Comment: I think the possibility of the input being in the format NEW 12345 YORK WALL STREET is minimal. There is no simple way of pulling street number and name as there is multiple ways of depicting this. If you force your input into a strict format.ie number street city zip you  will still have the problems. With  the Number it could be 4, 4b, 4/3, Apt4 etc. With Street new st, new broad st, broadway, broad way,etc.